# To Get the time when data is entered into database in ASP.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to find the time at which Data is entered into my database. I'm using SQL Server as my database.

```
public class OtpchangeController : Controller
{
    DateTime dbTime;
    // GET: Otpchange
    public ActionResult Generateotp()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Generateotp(tblPassword obj)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        using (PasswordGenerationEntities db = new PasswordGenerationEntities())
        {
            tblPassword newObj = (from c in db.tblPasswords
                                  where c.Username == obj.Username
                                  select c).First();
            if(newObj != null)
            {
                int num = r.Next();
                string newOtp = num.ToString();
                newObj.Otp = newOtp;
                db.SaveChanges();
                dbTime = DateTime.Now;
                Session["Username"] = newObj.Username.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(tblPassword obj)
    {
        string name = @Session["Username"].ToString();
        using (PasswordGenerationEntities db = new PasswordGenerationEntities())
        {

            tblPassword newObj = (from c in db.tblPasswords
                                  where c.Otp == obj.Otp && c.Username == name
                                  select c).First();
            DateTime formTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan result = dbTime.Subtract(formTime);
            newObj.Password = obj.Password;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        //return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Success()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Here I want to find difference between the time when otp is added into database and the time when that otp is entered by the user.

But dbTime comes as `01/01/2001`

But `formTime` is correct, also I want to find the difference between those time.

Comment: "dbTime" is a local variable, and it can't be retained across HTTP requests. Consider preserving its state by storing it in a session or TempData

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code you provided is not compiling or some parts are missing.

Anyway said I would suggest checking the msdn documentation about dbContext and its features [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx)

You can delegate the database log to a console log or another more suitable provider(log4net or a simple custom log file). Those logs contain information about database execution times.

In your case you could do :

```
    using (PasswordGenerationEntities db = new PasswordGenerationEntities())
    {
        db.Database.Log = Console.Write; 
        tblPassword newObj = (from c in db.tblPasswords
                              where c.Username == obj.Username
                              select c).First();
        if(newObj != null)
        {
            int num = r.Next();
            string newOtp = num.ToString();
            newObj.Otp = newOtp;
            db.SaveChanges();
            dbTime = DateTime.Now;
            Session["Username"] = newObj.Username.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword");
        }
    }
```

Check the console ouput.

[Console Database info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYnuH.png)

Comment: I can't find the difference between your code and my code, Sorry i'm new to asp.net